# Python 2.7 regex gets version from drupal plugins?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
import re
data = """
Views 2.x-dev
Viewfield 6.x-2.x, xxxx-xx-xx
Version 6.x-2.3
ctools 7.x-1.x-dev
XML sitemap 6.x-1, 2009-08-24
6.x-1.6
"""
print data
```

---

How to get `2.x-dev, 6.x-2.x, 6.x-2.3, 7.x-1.x-dev, 6.x-1 6.x-1.6`.
Thanks

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try [**`\b\d\.[-.xdev\d]+\b`**](https://regex101.com/r/xM2hR5/1) as regex.

Comment: regex = '\d\.[-.xdev\w]+'
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find this solution satisfactory:

```
import re

data = """
Views 2.x-dev
Viewfield 6.x-2.x, xxxx-xx-xx
Version 6.x-2.3
ctools 7.x-1.x-dev
XML sitemap 6.x-1, 2009-08-24
6.x-1.6
"""
## Solution 1: 
## 1) Finds all results that matches with the pattern 
## '<number>.x-<other_chars>' in a not greedy way 
## (that is why the '?')
## 2) Treat the found match and remove any ','

results = []
for result in re.findall( r"[0-9]\.x{1}\-.*x?", data ):
    results.append(result.split(",")[0])

print (results)

## Solution 2: (and my favourite)
## Create a list with those words that matches the pattern 
## <number>.x at their beginning
## The words are the result of splitting the 'data' with the
## split function from the regex module with a
## non-capturing version of regular parentheses.

result = [ x  for x in re.split(r'(?:,|\s)\s*', data) \ 
           if re.match(r'^[0-9].x',x) ]

print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\b\d\.[-.xdev\d]+\b')

data = """
Views 2.x-dev
Viewfield 6.x-2.x, xxxx-xx-xx
Version 6.x-2.3
ctools 7.x-1.x-dev
XML sitemap 6.x-1, 2009-08-24
6.x-1.6
"""

versions = rx.findall(data)
print(versions)
# ['2.x-dev', '6.x-2.x', '6.x-2.3', '7.x-1.x-dev', '6.x-1', '6.x-1.6']
```

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xM2hR5/1).